# Serverless - Referencing api gateway address in CloudFront origin definition

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

Using Serverless Framework,
i am creating an api gateway in my template :

```
functions
   test:
     handler: test.handler
     events:
      - http:
        path: save-subscription
        method: post
        cors: false
```

later on i want to use this api address xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/
as a domain name of an oigin of my cloudfront origins

```
DomainName: xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
OriginPath: dev
```

Is there a way to reference the api address dynamically/programmatically before it even exist, and do I need to use depends on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
  -   DomainName:
         Fn::Join:
          - ""
          -   -   "Ref": "ApiGatewayRestApi"
              - ".execute-api.${self:custom.region}.amazonaws.com"
```

worked for me.
Found the answer here : https://www.richdevelops.dev/blog/how-do-i-get-my-api-gateway-url